# Overloading indexing operators `()` and `{}` for custom classes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I would like to be able to overload the indexing operators  `()` and `{}` for my class in MATLAB. In particular, I want to be able to define the class methods like...

```
% ...
classdef MyClass < handle

    % ... other class definition stuff...

    function returnVal = operator{}(indexRange)
        %....implementation here....
    end
    function returnVal = operator()(indexRange)
        %....implementation here....
    end
end
```

so that I can create objects and do...

```
x = MyClass();
returnedVals = x(:);
returnedCells = [x{:}];

% etc.
```

Is this possible in MATLAB? I know this is easy in C++ and python ( by overloading `operator []` and `__get__` operators respectively ). The Mathworks site itself was not too clear on how to do this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [overload the `subsref` and `subsasgn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-numel-subsref-and-subsasgn.html) functions within your `classdef`.  The Mathworks provides a [full example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-with-modified-indexing.html) of how it works.  And note that if you wish to use your overloaded method *within* your class, you need to [call it explicitly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br09nsm).

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to implement `subsref` and `subsasgn`, you also need to implement:

1. size
2. length
3. ndims
4. numel
5. end

You should also consider implementing `subsindex`.

Comment: Why `length`? Doesn't `length` just do `max(size(x))` (or 0 for empty), so you should be OK if you've done `size` already? Or does `length` not actually go via `size`?

Comment: Hm, not sure, I've always implemented `length` too.

Answer (score 0):

On the MATLAB website, the guide [Class with Modified Index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020b/matlab/matlab_oop/class-with-modified-indexing.html) shows how to overload the `.`, `()` and `{}` operators via the `subsref` method (More recent documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html)).

Here is the snippet they provide for a class with a property called `Data`:

```
function sref = subsref(obj,s)
   % obj(i) is equivalent to obj.Data(i)
   switch s(1).type
      case '.'
         sref = builtin('subsref',obj,s);
      case '()'
         if length(s) < 2
            sref = builtin('subsref',obj.Data,s);
         else
            sref = builtin('subsref',obj,s);
         end
      case '{}'
         error('MYDataClass:subsref',...
            'Not a supported subscripted reference')
   end
end
```

In MATLAB R2021b and later, MathWorks recommends a new methods for overloading indexing operators, described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html).